# Compare each row with other rows of matrix

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient solution for the following problem:

```
b <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0), nrow = 2, byrow = T)
weight <- c(1,1)

times <- 5

abc <- do.call(rbind, replicate(times, b, simplify=FALSE))
weight <- rep.int(weight,times)

sum1 <- as.numeric(rep.int(NA,nrow(abc)))

##Rprof()
for(j in 1:nrow(abc)){
  a <- abc[j,]
  sum1[j] <- sum(weight[rowSums(t(a == t(abc)) + 0) == ncol(abc)])

}
##Rprof(NULL)
##summaryRprof()
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Rprof shows that rowSums(), t(), == and + are quite slow. If nrows is 20,000 it takes like 21 seconds.

Thanks for helping!

Edit: I have a matrix abc and a vector weight with length equal to nrow(abc). The first value of weight corresponds to the first row of matrix abc and so on... Now, I would like to determine which rows of matrix abc are equal. Then, I want to remember the position of those rows in order to sum up the corresponding weights which have the same position. The appropriate sum I wanna store for each row.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: What did you tried? Are you aware of apppy family functions?

Comment: I am not sure how to use apply functions here. I am not really familiar with apply functions.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to see what im trying to do, if one set "times" equal to 10. then running the code gives for exmaple for the first row a value of 5 in my vector "sum1" since there are 5 rows in matrix having values (0,0,0) and all of them are weighted with 1.

Comment: Please check your example, as I don't get what you are describing.

Comment: i am sorry. now it should work. a commata was missing and times is equal to 5 now. see above in my original post. to you get my idea?

Comment: In your example, it is simply `sum1 <- rep(times, nrow(abc))`. Not sure it is really useful...

Comment: i just took some random numbers. if rows are different they usually have a different sum. however, if rows are equal they must have the same sum.

Comment: rowSums(t(a == t(abc)) + 0) == ncol(abc)  ... this is my comparison  which is quite slow unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that looks valid and fast:

```
ff <- function(mat, weights)
{
   rs <- apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse = ";")
   unlist(lapply(unique(rs), 
                 function(x) 
                      sum(weights[match(rs, x, 0) > 0])))[match(rs, unique(rs))]
}

ff(abc, weight)
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

And comparing with your function:

```
ffOP <- function(mat, weights) 
{
   sum1 <- as.numeric(rep.int(NA,nrow(mat)))
   for(j in 1:nrow(mat)) {
       a <- mat[j,]
       sum1[j] <- sum(weights[rowSums(t(a == t(mat)) + 0) == ncol(mat)])
   }
   sum1
}
ffOP(abc, weight)
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

library(microbenchmark)
m = do.call(rbind, replicate(1e3, matrix(0:11, 3, 4), simplify = F))
set.seed(101); w = runif(1e3*3)
all.equal(ffOP(m, w), ff(m, w))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark(ffOP(m, w), ff(m, w), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq    median         uq        max neval
# ffOP(m, w) 969.83968 986.47941 996.68563 1015.53552 1051.23847    10
#   ff(m, w)  20.42426  20.64002  21.36508   21.97182   22.59127    10
```

For the record, I, also, implemented your approach in C and here are the benchmarkings:

```
#> microbenchmark(ffOP(m, w), ff(m, w), ffC(m, w), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq    median         uq        max neval
# ffOP(m, w) 957.66691 967.09429 991.35232 1000.53070 1016.74100    10
#   ff(m, w)  20.60243  20.85578  21.70578   22.13434   23.04924    10
#  ffC(m, w)  36.24618  36.40940  37.18927   37.39877   38.83358    10
```